# Next.js Server Component 'use server' behavior without declaration

Tags: next.js, react-server-components

I’m using the Server Component feature in Next.js, which requires declaring `'use client'` or `'use server'` at the beginning of the jsx file. I remember that `'use server'` is the default processing method, so it doesn’t need to be written.

However, I found that if I don’t write `'use server'` in the file where I call the API, I will see the data of this API in the network tab of the browser. If I write `'use server'`, the network tab of the browser will not have the data of this API, but I can still call this API and read the data.

What is the reason for this? Should I write `'use server'` in the file or not?

Here is the images:

don't write `'use server'` has the data of this API:

[image]

write `'use server'` will not show the API:

[image]

--

And my Snippet code:

```
'use server'
import axios from 'axios'

const apiTSEIndexUrl = '/IX0001'

export async function fetchTSEIndex() {
  try {
    const headers = {
      'X-API-KEY': process.env.API_KEY as string,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    const payload = {
      fields: 'open,high,low,close,volume'
    }
    const response = await axios.get(apiTSEIndexUrl, {
      headers: headers,
      params: payload,
    })
    return response.data.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error:', error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I remember that 'use server' is the default processing method, so it
> doesn’t need to be written.

I am not sure if your statement is correct. `use server` declares that functions on that file are marked as server actions and server actions run on the server. server actions are not part of the client bundle because we wouldn’t want sensitive server-side logic to be exposed or run on the client-side. The network tab in the browser's developer tools typically displays network activity initiated by the client-side code running in the browser.

[from docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/use-server)

> 'use server' marks server-side functions that can be called from
> client-side code.